# SVN output encoding in PowerShell

Tags: svn, powershell, character-encoding

I'm trying to capture an SVN log in a string inside a PowerShell script.

On the command line, the encoding of the output is correct, but as soon as I capture it in a string it is not:

```
PS C:\sandbox> svn log -r1804 https://myserver.here/svn/myrepo
--------------------------------------------------------------
r1804 | myname | 2012-06-07 | 1 line
Here is my log message with a special caractère
--------------------------------------------------------------
PS C:\sandbox> $tempStr = svn log -r1804 https://myserver.here/svn/myrepo | Out-String
PS C:\sandbox> $tempStr
--------------------------------------------------------------
r1804 | myname | 2012-06-07 | 1 line
Here is my log message with a special caractÃ©re
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

If it can help, here is the value of $OutputEncoding on my system:

```
IsSingleByte      : True
BodyName          : us-ascii
EncodingName      : US-ASCII
HeaderName        : us-ascii
WebName           : us-ascii
WindowsCodePage   : 1252
IsBrowserDisplay  : False
IsBrowserSave     : False
IsMailNewsDisplay : True
IsMailNewsSave    : True
EncoderFallback   : System.Text.EncoderReplacementFallback
DecoderFallback   : System.Text.DecoderReplacementFallback
IsReadOnly        : True
CodePage          : 20127
```

Thanks !!

**EDIT:**

I've also tried the XML output from SVN as follow, but with no luck!

```
$CmdLine = "svn log -r40:HEAD https://myserver.here/svn/myrepo --xml";

$Logs = [xml](Invoke-Expression $CmdLine);

foreach ($Commit in $Logs.log.logentry)
{
   Write-Host $Commit.msg;
}
```

**EDIT #2:**

I don't know if it may help, but I've noticed that the same issue is there simply using the XML output format directly on the PowerShell console prompt:

```
PS C:\repo> svn log -r999:999
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r999 | myname | 2013-05-29 09:48:20 +0200 (mer., 29 mai 2013) | 2 lines

Log message line #1 with a special 'caractère'
Log message line #2
------------------------------------------------------------------------

PS C:\repo> svn log -r999:999 --xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<log>
<logentry
   revision="999">
<author>myname</author>
<date>2013-05-29T07:48:20.915930Z</date>
<msg>Log message line #1 with a special 'caractÃ©re'
Log message line #2</msg>
</logentry>
</log>
```

Comment: Same behaviour without piping to out-string?

Comment: Yes, exactly the same :(

Answer (score 2):

Try to put this:

```
$OutputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding
```

before your svn call.

Comment: I tested this
`$OutputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding
$ChangeLog = Invoke-Expression $CmdLine | Out-String`
where `$CmdLine` is my svn command.
Still the same problem unfortunately...

Comment: What locale are you using on your PC? Would guess the French one, no?

Comment: @YannickBlondeau try with `$OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode` or [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8

Comment: @David Yep, exactly. Would this be an issue ?

Answer (score 1):

It is not directly powershell friendly, but [SharpSvn](http://sharpsvn.net) provides the Subversion api directly to .Net, so with that you don't need any parsing at all.

If you are using 'svn log' I would recommend using --xml to avoid having to cope with future output changes.

svn's output is UTF-8 which is transferred to Windows as Unicode, so I would recommend reading as Unicode.

Answer (score 1):

This blog post [Powershell, SVN Log, and Encodings](http://blag.koveras.net/2013/08/16/powershell-svn-log-and-encodings/) explains and solved quite similar problem with SVN encoding in Powershell. It works for me.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer but unfortunately this does not solve the issue for me :(

Answer (score 1):

I've had luck with:

```
$enc = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding($Host.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.OEMCodePage)
$output = $enc.GetBytes((svn log --xml))
[xml] $result = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($output)
```