# Encoding issue when using Native CMD Command from Powershell

Tags: powershell, unicode, encoding, cmd

When Executing native cmd command from powershell, e.g `net view \\192.168.1.x` I get the following results which non-English chars shown as `????` :

```
Share name        Type   Used as  Comment
--------------------------------------------------
AntEater          Disk
AntEater_Eab      Disk
HP  M4345 ?????   Print           HP  M4345 ?????
Letters           Disk
SMSCenter         Disk
temp              Disk
Users             Disk
????? ??? ??????  Print           ????? ??? ??????
The command completed successfully.
```

if I run `chcp 862` I get the following results (on the console):

```
Share name        Type   Used as  Comment
--------------------------------------------------
AntEater          Disk
AntEater_Eab      Disk
HP  M4345 הנהחש   Print           HP  M4345 הנהחש
Letters           Disk
SMSCenter         Disk
temp              Disk
Users             Disk
מדפסת             Print
```

Which is fine, but when I try to save it to a variable or export it to a file:

```
$temp = net view \\192.168.1.x
$temp

Share name        Type   Used as  Comment
--------------------------------------------------
AntEater          Disk
AntEater_Eab      Disk
HP  M4345 ?????   Print           HP  M4345 ?????
Letters           Disk
SMSCenter         Disk
temp              Disk
Users             Disk
????? ??? ??????  Print           ????? ??? ??????
```

the results are wrong again,

I've already tried:

```
net view \\192.168.1.x | Out-File C:\temp.txt -Encoding Unicode
cmd /c 'chcp 862 && net view \\192.168.1.x' | Out-File C:\temp.txt -Encoding Unicode
cmd /c 'chcp 862 && net view \\192.168.1.x > c:\temp.txt'
cmd /u /c 'chcp 862 && net view \\192.168.1.x > c:\temp.txt'
```

and much more really...

The Issue shown as well when running `net view \\192.168.1.x | Out-String`

The same results are whether I run it from CMD or PowerShell

Do you know the behavior? how can I save the correct output to a variable or file?

Comment: What about looking at this then.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10931984/svn-output-encoding-in-powershell. Same as what I was trying to say perhaps with more explanation.

Comment: Looks like it is problem with `net` command: it does not honor console code page when output has redirected. You can compare output of `net view \\192.168.1.x` and `net view \\192.168.1.x|more` in CMD prompt.

Comment: @PetSerAl i guess you right, any idea then?

Comment: @Matt thanks, didn't find there any solution though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After changing the "language for non-Unicode programs" in the control panel, the problem solved, thanks for your help...

[image]

Run `intl.cpl` and select the `Adminstrative` tab.

Comment: `Set-WinSystemLocale he-IL`