# Pass UTF8 parameter in powershell

Tags: powershell, utf-8, ffmpeg

I have to use ffmpeg-normalize (https://github.com/slhck/ffmpeg-normalize) in my project.

Everything works well except that encoding have trouble on Windows:

```
$OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode
$OutputEncoding
Get-WinSystemLocale
pause
Get-ChildItem -path "./" -recurse | foreach ($_) {
    if ($_.Extension -eq ".wav") { 
    write $_.FullName
     ffmpeg-normalize $_.FullName -nt peak -t -20 -o $_.FullName -f
     pause
    }
    if ($_.Extension -eq ".mp4") { 
     ffmpeg-normalize $_.FullName -c:a aac -nt peak -t -20 -o $_.FullName -f
    }
        if ($_.Extension -eq ".mp3") { 
     ffmpeg-normalize $_.FullName -c:a libmp3lame -nt peak -t -20 -o $_.FullName -f
    }
}
```

and here is the display

```
BodyName          : utf-16
EncodingName      : Unicode
HeaderName        : utf-16
WebName           : utf-16
WindowsCodePage   : 1200
IsBrowserDisplay  : False
IsBrowserSave     : True
IsMailNewsDisplay : False
IsMailNewsSave    : False
IsSingleByte      : False
EncoderFallback   : System.Text.EncoderReplacementFallback
DecoderFallback   : System.Text.DecoderReplacementFallback
IsReadOnly        : True
CodePage          : 1200

Parent                         : en
LCID                           : 1033
KeyboardLayoutId               : 1033
Name                           : en-US
IetfLanguageTag                : en-US
DisplayName                    : English (United States)
NativeName                     : English (United States)
EnglishName                    : English (United States)
TwoLetterISOLanguageName       : en
ThreeLetterISOLanguageName     : eng
ThreeLetterWindowsLanguageName : ENU
CompareInfo                    : CompareInfo - en-US
TextInfo                       : TextInfo - en-US
IsNeutralCulture               : False
CultureTypes                   : SpecificCultures, InstalledWin32Cultures, FrameworkCultures
NumberFormat                   : System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo
DateTimeFormat                 : System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo
Calendar                       : System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar
OptionalCalendars              : {System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar, System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar}
UseUserOverride                : True
IsReadOnly                     : False

Press Enter to continue...:
C:\Users\user\Desktop\a\b\d\e\audio - Copy.wav
WARNING: Output file only supports one stream. Keeping only first audio stream.
Press Enter to continue...:
C:\Users\user\Desktop\a\b\d\不\audio - Copy.wav
ERROR: file C:\Users\user\Desktop\a\b\d\?\audio - Copy.wav does not exist
Press Enter to continue...:
C:\Users\user\Desktop\a\c\audio - Copy.wav
WARNING: Output file only supports one stream. Keeping only first audio stream.
Press Enter to continue...:
```

The program works well on MacOS, so I don't think it's a software issue. It looks like PowerShell does not send the parameter to the program correctly.

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: There's a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34510700/encoding-issue-when-using-native-cmd-command-from-powershell. What does `Get-WinSystemLocale` return?

Comment: Thanks ! by activating the support of the UTF8 in all programs it works like a charm !